# Does a WCF REST service return a response to the client even if a secondary thread is not done running?

Tags: multithreading, wcf, mixpanel

I'm trying to implement some analytics logic in my WCF REST web service but I don't want to damage performance while I do so.
I was thinking of starting a new thread that would communicate with the analytics service (Mixpanel) while the main thread does the actual work but I'm not sure this accomplishes what I want to do.

My assumption is that the web service would return a response as soon as its main thread is done while the secondary thread runs on its own and may run longer without the client waiting any extra time.

Is that an accurate assumption?

Answer (score 1):

Some testing showed that my assumption was accurate.